# Sum Column that matches a given criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

How would I sum vertically the columns that meet a given criteria?

For example:

```
A B C D E F G
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If criteria = A, then the formula would give me 4
if B, 8
if C, 12. I would like the criteria input to be a reference-able cell.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You say "columns" (plural). Is it possible that more than one column meets the criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX to return the correct array.  Use MATCH to return the correct column:

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:5,0,MATCH(J1,1:1,0)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the reply. By A B C D..., I wasn't referring to the column labels. Instead, they are A B C D... in cells as an example.

Comment: @DH see edit.  If this works please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a sheet like this:
[image]

```
=SUM(INDEX($BF$5:$BI$16,,Match($BC$5,$BF$4:$BI$4,0)))
```